# How to append contents to a div gradually, while the loop executes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am trying to display Bible contents from an xml. It's a phonegap app. I have functions to get the following from the xml:

1. Array of book names -> getAllBooks() Stores names into an array 'books[]'
2. Number of chapters in a book -> getChapterCount(book)
3. Number of verses in a chapter -> getVerseCount(book,chapter)
4. The verse text -> getVerse(book,chapter,verse)

Now I am trying to display the whole bible into a div using jquery. I'm using the following function:

```
function showWholeBible() {
    getAllBooks();
    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= parseInt(getChapterCount(books[i])); j++) {
            for (var k = 1; k <= parseInt(getVerseCount(books[i], j)); k++) {
                $('#bibleDiv').append(getVerse(books[i], j, k));
                // alert(getVerse(books[i],j,k));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Its taking a very, very long time for the div to display the content. And the content is getting displayed only when the whole set of loops completes.

Is there any way to append each verse to the div the same time the commented alert above pops up? So that a gradual appending occurs..?

Or is there any other alternative to improve the loading time?

Comment: refer this: http://blog.jacobsonhome.com/2013/04/a-javascript-long-running-background.html

Comment: The UI isn't updated until the loop completes because JS is single threaded. You could try putting your nested loops inside `setTimeout` calls with a very low interval, although this may not work in all browsers. A better solution would be to only show the content needed on the page. Showing an entire book in one page is completely pointless IMO.

Comment: Use `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to run code periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it takes a long time ... 
as you build up your HTML the browser doesn't know how to display it ... at least in the way you are doing it. So it waits until it has all HTML elements available.

Then it can build his DOM tree ... (I'm simplifying here ... its more complicated that that -
read it up [here](http://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm))

So what you need to do is add some logic to load the `<div>` only when the user scrolls down then next `<div>` is displayed.

This is called lazy loading and can be achieved with JavaScript ... look at some javascript frameworks ... most of them provide this type of logic out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setTimeout()` to queue up the verse-adding logic so that the browser has time to render each verse before adding the next one.

So I would create a function to append the verse:

```
var $bible = $('#bibleDiv'); // cache this to avoid having to find it every time
var versesAppended = 0;
function displayVerse(book, chapterIndex, verseIndex) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $bible.append(getVerse(book, chapterIndex, verseIndex);
    }, versesAppended * 10); // even 0 ms delay is enough to allow the browser to render it
    versesAppended++;
}
```

Then your code just uses that function:

```
function showWholeBible() {
    getAllBooks();
    for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 1; j <= parseInt(getChapterCount(books[i])); j++) {
            for (var k = 1; k <= parseInt(getVerseCount(books[i], j)); k++) {
                displayVerse(books[i], j, k);
                // alert(getVerse(books[i],j,k));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck. Still waits for the loop to complete. Im doing it in phonegap, webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it might be little faster.

```
function showWholeBible() {
getAllBooks();
var conatainer = $('#bibleDiv');
for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j <= parseInt(getChapterCount(books[i])); j++) {
        for (var k = 1; k <= parseInt(getVerseCount(books[i], j)); k++) {
            conatainer.append(getVerse(books[i], j, k));
            // alert(getVerse(books[i],j,k));
        }
    }
}
}
```

As its search **bibleDiv** only once in the DOM